# Сетка на гридах в IE

Tags: css, css-grid

Делаю сетку на гридах, во всех браузерах отрабатывает хорошо,но в IE все сплющено(([image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.grid {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: (1fr)[12];
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12,1fr);
  margin: 0 -15px
}
.grid-item {
  margin: 0 15px
}
.grid-item_1 {
  -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  grid-column-end: span 1;
  margin: 0 15px
}
.grid-item_sm-1 {
  -ms-grid-column-span: 12;
  grid-column-end: span 12;
  margin: 0 15px
}
.grid-item_md-1 {
  -ms-grid-column-span: 12;
  grid-column-end: span 12;
  margin: 0 15px
}
.grid-item_lg-1 {
  -ms-grid-column-span: 12;
  grid-column-end: span 12;
  margin: 0 15px
}
.grid-item_xl-1 {
  -ms-grid-column-span: 12;
  grid-column-end: span 12;
  margin: 0 15px
}
```

Comment: `IE` не поддерживает css grid, либо поддерживает не полностью.

Comment: @Grundy, точнее сказать, что они поддерживают старую версию (IE>9) https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-css3-grid-layout-20110407

Comment: Нет смысла поддерживать IE11 в 2020 году. А если и поддерживать (но лучше не надо), то не стоит использовать ни гриды, ни даже флексы.

Comment: @andreymal, флексы вроде норм